# How to pass a Array of GL_TEXTURE_2D to the shader?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, texture2d

I know how to pass a single Texture_2D to my shader in lwjgl using:

```
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadowMapper.depthMap);
```

but how can I pass an array?

Comment: Make a "sampler2d" array in the shader then pass the texture unit's ID's an an integer so "arrayname[pos]" will be the ID of the texture unit you bound the texture.

Comment: @KriszDev: In principle, that will work. However, I'd like to add that there are serious limitations with arrays of sampler uniforms in GLSL. In versions <= 3.30, only contant indices can be used, in 4.x, this has been relaxed to dynamically uniform expressions, but it is still far from the random access one typically expects from arrays.

Comment: Consider using an [array texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture)